# What is the equivalent JVM in C#?

Tags: c#, java

The JVM is required to run a java application.

I wanted to know is there any equivalent in c#?

If yes what is it?

Comment: Why you folks underestimate wikipedia, BTW?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8bs2ecf4.aspx) or CLR. This is the runtime that supports not just C# but also other .NET languages, such as Visual Basic.NET. Typically, each language exposes developers to a subset of the features available on the CLR (for instance, method overloading purely by return type is not generally supported in C#, but is supported by the CLR).

Just as Java compiles to bytecode, C# and other .NET languages compile to Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) - the only language to expose the complete set of CLR features.

Of course, C# is [defined purely as a language](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm). There's no reason why it cannot be *made* to run on other runtimes, or indeed in an interpreted mode. But the "equivalent" of "the" JVM (implying the default one) is the CLR.

Comment: That's not true. You don't need the CLR to run C# code, *any* CLI-compliant runtime will do. Also, not all implementations of C# compile to MSIL, actually I believe most compile to CIL and some to native code. In fact, not all implementations of C# are compiled *at all*, I believe that there is at least one interpreter.

Comment: No, my answer is true, the other one isn't. This is the default runtime for C#, as the JVM is for Java. I haven't actually said that you MUST have the CLR to run C# code - that wasn't the question.

Comment: Someone COULD write a true compiler for Java, that is, compile it to machine code and not need a JVM. Someone COULD write an interpreter for Java. Maybe by now someone has done one or both of these things. Ditto for C#.

Comment: @Jay - Nobody's denying that. But the question is based on Java's interaction with the JVM, and the C#/.NET equivalent.

Comment: JVM != (JIT compiler || interpreter). A Java app compiled to machine code would still need the garbage collector, JNI, reflection, and all the other JVM functionality to be available at run time.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong because the wording makes it sound like the two frameworks operate the same way. There is no JVM equivalent to .NET, because .NET does not run sandboxed in a virtual machine like Java does. Both are completely different.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have Common Language Runtime (CLR ) to run C# applications.

Comment: The way this is worded, this is not *strictly* true - see Jörg's comment to my answer, and my edit.

Answer (score 4):

There is no .NET equivalent to the JVM, because .NET does not run inside a virtualized sandbox like Java does.

Java: Source > Java Bytecode > Intepreted by JVM compiled for specific platform.

.NET: Source > MSIL > Compiled to native code the first time the MSIL assembly is executed.

As such, .NET code can be compiled into MSIL, moved to a different machine architecture, and so long as something (like Mono) can read that MSIL and compile to machine code, it will work. With Java, the code will always run sandboxed inside the JVM.

Java and .NET have similar architectures, but they are also very different in other regards. In this instance, Java addresses platform dependence by defining a single universal virtual platform that all Java code runs on, whereas .NET instead defines its language and libraries as platform independent.

With Java the only people that can lawfully offer a JVM on a specific platform is Oracle/Sun/Java. With .NET anyone can decide to implement a version of the CLR in parts or in totality on a given platform.